# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when i need push item to one of property of interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this model :

```
    export interface AddAlbumeModel {
    name: string;
    gener: string;
    signer: string;
    albumeProfile:any;
    albumPoster:any;
    tracks:TrackMode[];
}

export interface TrackMode {
    trackNumber: number;
    trackName: string;
    trackProfile: any;
    trackPoster:any;
    trackFile: any;
}
```

And I want to add `tracks` with this code :

```
let addModel = {} as AddAlbumeModel;

for (let index = 0; index < this.addAlbumFG.controls['tracks']['controls'].length; index++) {

 const item= this.addAlbumFG.controls['tracks']['controls'][index]['controls'];

 addModel.tracks.push({
    trackFile:item.trackFile.value['files'][0],
    trackNumber:item.trackNumber.value,
    trackName:item.trackName.value,
    trackPoster:item.trackPoster.value['files'][0],
    trackProfile:item.trackProfile.value['files'][0]
  })
}
```

But it shows me this error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

**how can I solve this problem ???**

Comment: You should initialize tracks array , before use .push method . if(!addModel.tracks){addModel.tracks = [];} else {addModel.tracks.push()}

Comment: You can check if tracks exist before making a push to it.
Just replace addModel.tracks.push with
addModel.tracks  && addModel.tracks.push

Answer (score 0):

Hi below error came because you did not declare available as an array:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Do first:

```
let addModel = {} as AddAlbumeModel;
addModel.tracks = [];
for (let index = 0; index < this.addAlbumFG.controls['tracks']['controls'].length; 
index++) {

const item= this.addAlbumFG.controls['tracks']['controls'][index]['controls'];

addModel.tracks.push({
trackFile:item.trackFile.value['files'][0],
trackNumber:item.trackNumber.value,
trackName:item.trackName.value,
trackPoster:item.trackPoster.value['files'][0],
trackProfile:item.trackProfile.value['files'][0]
})
}
```

Now done :)

Answer (score 0):

The above fails because the property `tracks` is undefined.
In typescript, Interfaces are used for type checking only, interfaces are lost after the code is transpiled to JavaScript.

Here you have a couple of solutions:

#### Initialize property before using it

One thing you can do is initialize tracks before you use it.

```
interface TrackMode {
   // props
}

interface AddAlbumeModel {
    // other props
    tracks: TrackMode[];
}

let addModel: AddAlbumeModel = {
    tracks: []
} as AddAlbumeModel;

addModel.tracks.push(...)
```

#### Use class instead of interface

Interfaces can't have default values but classes can, so you can use a class instead and set defaults value for `tracks` as an empty array.

```
interface TrackMode {
   // props
}

class AddAlbumeModel {
    // other props
    tracks: TrackMode[] = [];
}

const addModel = new AddAlbumeModel()

addModel.tracks.push(...)
```